# reading secret azure pipeline variables in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-pipelines, secret-key

I originally marked the variables as secret like this:
[variables tab on azure pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNxe0.png)

I have set my environment variables in azure pipeline like this:

```
steps:
- bash:
  env:
    MASKED_AZURE_CLIENT_ID: "$(MASKED_AZURE_CLIENT_ID)"
```

And I'm trying to use this client Id here:

```
var azureClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MASKED_AZURE_CLIENT_ID", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", azureClientId);
```

When I run the pipeline, and try to use these credentials to access my keyvault, they aren't being found through my code, and subsequently my tests fail. However, when I use a non-secret AZURE_CLIENT_ID, I am able to access that variable in C# and use it in my code. Is there a way where I access a secret Azure Pipeline Variable within my C# code?

Comment: What is the relationship between the `bash` step definition and the C# code here? It would be unusual, although not necessarily a problem if that's what you want to do, to run an executable compiled from C# *in a pipeline*. Where and how does this code run?

Comment: I seemed to have figured it out, I switched from using a bash step definition to using a PowerShell one, and switching the script to set the variables at runtime with vso